# Access to Flask Global Variables in Blueprint Apps

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

my source code has this structure:

`main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    g.my_db = PostgreSQL()
    app.register_blueprint(my_app, url_prefix="/my_app")
```

`my_app.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, g
my_app = Blueprint("my_app", __name__)
@my_app.route("/")
def index():
    return g.my_db.fetch_all()   <<< ERROR
```

but it shows this error:

`AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'my_db'`

Even when I try to use `g` outside of app context, it shows this error:

`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

So how to set and access to global variables in Flask?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the data are lost when the context (`with app.app_context()`) ends [(doc)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data).

Inside the context, everything is ok :

```
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    g.my_db = 'database ok'
    print(g.my_db)

# >>> this prints 'database ok'
```

But outside, you cannot access the attribute :

```
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    g.my_db = 'database ok'

print(g.my_db)

# >>> this throws RuntimeError: Working outside of application context
```

even if you create a new context:

```
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    g.my_db = 'database ok'

with app.app_context():
    print(g.my_db)

>>> this throws AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'my_db'
```

Your best call should be to declare the database object before the context, and then import it. Or maybe you can create it directly inside `my_app.py` where you need it ?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question. would you please take an example?

Comment: i don't know the structure of your project, where do you need the database object, only in your module `my_app` ?

Comment: In all modules (apps) of project.

Comment: it's hard to tell more to avoid circular imports nightmares. Don't store the database object inside `g`. For example you can create it inside the `__init__.py` of the apps root folder (if you have one).  The code of your question is incomplete to reproduce and improve the structure you're using exactly.

Answer (score 2):

`g` isn't persistent in the way you're trying to use it. Write a function to create a connection each time you need it. Preferably use a database extension like Flask-SQLAlchemy to manage connections for you.

`db.py`:

```
import <postgresql dependencies>

def get_db():
   db = PostgreSQL()
   # config here
   return db
```

`main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_app, url_prefix="/my_app")
```

`my_app.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, g
from db import get_db

my_app = Blueprint("my_app", __name__)

@my_app.route("/")
def index():
    db = get_db()
    data = db.fetch_all()
    db.close()
    return data
```